# How can I make Mono show multiple lines of a Label with Winforms?

Tags: c#, mono

I have a method that creates a label on the window. This method works fine in Windows under .Net but when I run it on my RPi using mono only one line appears.

Is there any mono specific code I can use to force mono to show all of the text on the label?

```
private void ShowMessageRight(string strMessage, Color backColor, Color foreColor, Single fontSize = 24f)
{
    if (_lblMessageRight == null)
    {
        _lblMessageRight = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(_lblMessageRight);
    }
    _lblMessageRight.Text = strMessage;
    _lblMessageRight.BackColor = backColor;
    _lblMessageRight.ForeColor = foreColor;
    _lblMessageRight.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), fontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
    _lblMessageRight.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    _lblMessageRight.MaximumSize = new Size(500, 0);
    _lblMessageRight.AutoSize = true;
    _lblMessageRight.Left = (int)((this.ClientSize.Width * 0.75) - (_lblMessageRight.Width / 2));
    _lblMessageRight.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - _lblMessageRight.Height) / 2;
    _lblMessageRight.BringToFront();
    _lblMessageRight.Show();
}
```

The result of identical calls to the method.

On Windows with .net
[image: This is on Windows]

On Linux with Mono (On RPi)
[image: This is on the RPi]

EDIT:

So I tried using TextRenderer.MeasureText this seems to work but I am very confused as to why. TextRenderer.MeasureText will sometimes return a width that is less than 500 when I know the string is longer than that. It will return a height that is twice the height that the font should be. if I use that value as the label height I get two lines.  TextRenderer.MeasureText some how magically knows how long wide I want my label.

```
    Size SingleLineSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(strMessage, _lblMessageLeft.Font, new Size(Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MaxValue));
    strMessage = SingleLineSize.Width + strMessage;
    int numberOfLines = (int)Math.Ceiling(SingleLineSize.Width / 500f);
    int lineHeight = SingleLineSize.Height;
    int height = numberOfLines * lineHeight;
```

Comment: `_lblMessageRight.MaximumSize = new Size(500, 0);`? Why 0?

Comment: From what I have read 0 means unlimited. So it can grow to infinity vertically.

Comment: That may implicitly mean that in .NET, but Mono has a stricter adherence to the "rules" and may not take that liberty. I would try setting it to something large and see if it works in Mono.

Comment: @Ron Beyer: Setting that to 100, 200, 300 makes makes no change. Setting it to 500 makes the app crash when loading with an index out of range exception.

Comment: I updated my Question with my current status.